# Dynamic Page Titles using MEAN stack - Jade and Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug, mean-stack

In my MEAN stack app I'm trying to change the page title (set in jade) according to the content loaded on the page. At the moment it displays a generic page title for every page within the SPA.

To set the page title for the index I'm doing this

index.js

```
 res.render('index', {
    title: 'Generic Page Title'
});
```

Then when I return content (different angular route/page) I want to update this title

offers.js

```
Offer.find(searchObject).sort('-pricing.pctSavings').exec(function(err, offers){
  if (err) {
    res.render('error', {
      status: 500
    });
  } else {
    //update title?
    res.jsonp(offers);
  }
});
```

head.jade

```
title= appName+' - '+title
```

I'm unsure how to change this as the offers are returned as json within the page. I've tried adding the title to the response (res.locals.title = 'Test unique title') but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Adding more information:

I can include some html in the jade template as follows:

head.jade

```
 head
   div(data-ng-include="'views/dynamic_title.html'")
   meta(charset='utf-8')
   meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge,chrome=1')
   meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no')
```

views/dynamic_title.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="OffersController">
    <title> Test </title> //works
    <title> {{test}} </title> //test set in offers controller - doesn't work
    <title> {{ Page.title() }}</title> //Page injected into offers controller - doesn't work
</div>
```

The offers controller isn't loaded until later...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood that you are not returning jade files every time request hit your server. Since SPA using angularjs, your app loads on demand data from the server. You have to change the title in your angular js code.

**HMTL**

```
<html ng-app="app">
   <head ng-controller="TitleCtrl">
     <title>{{ Page.title() }}</title>
    </head>
    ....
</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.factory('Page', function() {
   var title = 'default';
   return {
     title: function() { return title; },
     setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle }
   };
})
.controller('TitleCtrl', function($scope, Page) {
    $scope.Page = Page;
})
.controller('RouterPathCtrl', function($scope, Page) {
    Page.setTitle('My new title')
});
```

Whenever route changes,

```
Inject `Page` and Call `Page.setTitle()` from controllers.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see the edit as to the problem I'm still having...

Answer (score 1):

I think a way of achieving this is sending the current page title as a header with your response, so you dont have to put unrelated informations into your JSON model.

```
res.set("title", "some title");
```

[API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set)

Then I with a combination of request interceptors and directives I would read out the header and update the title-tag depending on that header field.

```
module.factory("Page", function() {
  return {
    title: "index"
  }
});
module.directive("title", ["Page",
  function(Page) {

    return {
      restrict:"E",
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          return Page.title;
        }, function(newValue) {
          $element.html(newValue);
        })
      }
    }
  }
]);
module.factory("PageTitleInterceptor", ["Page",
  function(Page) {
    return {
      response: function(response) {
        Page.title = response.headers("title");
        return response;
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

See that Plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNSUnqJkGXdTv9MfERYF?p=preview
With firebug you can observe the title-tag

regards

Comment: Content changes much more often using client code rather than server code in an AngularJS application, so the page title will need to be changed every time javascript (AngularJS) loads a new page view.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the page title using javascript from inside AngularJS controlers in the MEAN stack.

Simply run

```
document.title = "Current Page Title";
```

at the beginning of each controller.

Comment: This is one way of walking around the problem, but then the application becomes unmanageable when there are enough number of controllers across the whole app.